# How to remove alpha characters then format as numeric with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to remove known alpha substrings and format the result to display two digits after the decimal.

```
select tbl.result
, case
    when CHARINDEX('searchCriteria',tbl.result) > 0 then case
        when ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(tbl.result, 'searchCriteria', '')) > 0 then TRY_CONVERT(decimal(18,2),REPLACE(tbl.result, 'searchCriteria', ''))
    else REPLACE(tbl.result, 'searchCriteria', '')
    end
else tbl.result
end as [Substring_Removed]
from sourceTable tbl


--Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 71
--Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

Having trouble with [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

What strategies can I use to avoid this?

Typical values in the results column are in the style of:

- <123 searchCriteria
- 123 searchCriteria
- 1.23
- 123,000 searchCriteria
- 1.23x10e8 searchCriteria

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful

Comment: Typical data would be a numeric value followed by a unit of measure, or some manually entered value. I want to display the numeric without the unit of measure displayed with two digits after the decimal. 1,234.5 g/L would display as 1234.50

Comment: An example of a manually entered value found in the source column would be 'Not measured'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This is assuming "SomeString" begins with a number and has a space after the value.


Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeString varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<123 searchCriteria'),
(2,'123 searchCriteria'),
(3,'1.23'),
(4,'123,000 searchCriteria'),
(5,'1.23x10e8 searchCriteria'),
(6,'1,234.5 g/L'),
(7,'Not measured')


Select *
      ,TheValue = IsNull(Format(Try_Convert(float,Replace(Replace(Replace(Left(SomeString,CharIndex(' ',SomeString+' ')),',',''),'x10',''),'<','')),'#0.00'),SomeString)
 From @YourTable
```

Returns

```
ID  SomeString                  TheValue
1   <123 searchCriteria         123.00
2   123 searchCriteria          123.00
3   1.23                        1.23
4   123,000 searchCriteria      123000.00
5   1.23x10e8 searchCriteria    123000000.00
6   1,234.5 g/L                 1234.50
7   Not measured                Not measured
```

Comment: This solution does figure the scientific notation, which is good. But, it nulls out the non-numeric results, like 'Not measured'. This will not work for my situation. Also, I need the two decimal places for each numeric entry.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear regarding my requirements. A non-numeric result should display unaltered.  'Not measured' should display if not accompanied by a numeric value.

Comment: I think this is the most complete answer to my requirements. Thank you.

Comment: @DanR Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Using PatExclude8K, which you can find [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/T-SQL/117890/), you could do this:

```
-- Sample Data
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeString varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<123 searchCriteria'),
(2,'123 searchCriteria'),
(3,'1.23'),
(4,'123,000 searchCriteria'),
(5,'1.23x10e8 searchCriteria'),
(6,'1,234.5 g/L'),
(7,'Not measured')

-- Solution:
SELECT yt.*, [Substring_Removed] = 
         ISNULL(CAST(CAST(NewString AS decimal(10,2)) AS varchar(12)), SomeString)
FROM @YourTable yt
CROSS APPLY dbo.PatExclude8K(SomeString, '[^0-9.]');
```

Results:

```
ID          SomeString                   Substring_Removed
----------- ---------------------------- -----------------
1           <123 searchCriteria          123.00
2           123 searchCriteria           123.00
3           1.23                         1.23
4           123,000 searchCriteria       123000.00
5           1.23x10e8 searchCriteria     1.23
6           1,234.5 g/L                  1234.50
7           Not measured                 Not measured
```

**UPDATED for people who can't use any new functions...**

Here's the patexclude8K functionality baked right in to the solution:

```
-- Sample Data
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeString varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<123 searchCriteria'),
(2,'123 searchCriteria'),
(3,'1.23'),
(4,'123,000 searchCriteria'),
(5,'1.23x10e8 searchCriteria'),
(6,'1,234.5 g/L'),
(7,'Not measured')

-- new solution with Patexclude8K logic baked in
SELECT yt.*, substring_removed =  ISNULL(CAST(CAST(NewString AS decimal(10,2)) AS varchar(12)), yt.SomeString)
FROM @yourTable yt
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING(yt.someString, N, 1)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) a(x),
         (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) b(x),
         (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) c(x),
         (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) d(x)
  ) iTally(N)
  WHERE N <= (CONVERT(INT,LEN(yt.someString),0))
  AND 0 = PATINDEX('[^0-9.]',SUBSTRING(yt.someString COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,N,1))
  FOR XML PATH('')
) patexclude(newstring);
```

Results are the same but this method will be about 40% faster than what I originally posted because no special handling is needed for special XML characters.

Comment: These results are what I would expect. Unfortunately, in this project, I cannot implement any add-on functions.

Comment: I updated my solution to not require any additional functions. With the updated solution the patexclude8K functionality is baked into the query using CROSS APPLY.